# How to give access to programs to the Guest account?

Tags: 12.04, guest-session

I've got a fresh installation of Precise installed, and I installed Google Chrome from the administrator account.  Then, when I log into the Guest account I want to be able to use Chrome, but when I try to start it from unity it does nothing.  When trying to launch it from the command line, it gives me the error: `Failed to move to new PID namespace: Operation not permitted`.  How do i allow access to Chrome or other programs like this for the Guest account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, it's much easier to use the standard software repositories and the system's package managing system instead of installing applications manually. If you do a manual install, you're responsible for setting file and directory permissions correctly and much more.

So, the easiest solution would be to install the chromium packages ([chromium-browser](http://packages.ubuntu.com/chromium-browser) [image: Install chromium-browser]) using the software center, and to remove the manual install.

**EDIT:**
Alternatively, you could use [Google's PPA for Chrome](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/google_chrome) (thanks Andrejs Cainikovs - worth an answer on its own!).

Comment: How to install Chrome via repository: http://www.howopensource.com/2011/10/install-google-chrome-in-ubuntu-11-10-11-04-10-10-10-04/

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs: very good hint! I added it to my answer.